# Calculate the energy absorbed by a fluid as a function of the fluid depth

Tags: limits

The solar radiation, penetrating into the water body, decays with depth, as fluid layers absorb energy.

The form of the radiation equation inside the water can be expressed as:

$$ I=I_0.(0.36-0.08*ln(z)) $$

where $ I_0 $ and $ z $ denote for radiation at $ z=0 $ and depth respectively.

I want to calculate the energy absorbed in the fluid as a function of $ z $.

How can I do it?

If I take a finite difference element, this can be:

$$ Energy Gen=I_0.[(0.36-0.08*ln(z))-(0.36-0.08*ln(z+dz))] $$

which finally leads to the following relation:

$$ Energy Gen=I_0.[0.08*ln((z+dz)/z)] $$

In the above equation, we should have an infinite $ dz $.

So how can I have the absorbed energy as a function of $ z $., not $ dz $?

Comment: If you subtract the radiation at depth $z$ from $I_0$, that gives you absorbed radiation which is nothing but the absorbed energy per unit of surface area (depending on unit it is being represented in).

Comment: @MathLover I want the absorbed energy at the z location not the energy which is absorbed from 0 to z.

Comment: Then differentiate wrt $z$ and you will get the rate of change in energy at depth $z$.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, you are right. Many thanks to you